# X Session from Mac

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, x-server, xorg

How can I log into an X server from Mac OS X? I know that `ssh -X username@host` will log me in and I will have the *capability* to run X applications.

On Cygwin/X you can log in and have a whole X session from your computer... and it will look something like this:

[image]

How can I replicate this?

Using this batch script:

```
@echo off
SET DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0

SET REMOTE_HOST=%1

IF "%REMOTE_HOST%" == "" SET REMOTE_HOST=10.0.0.1

SET CYGWIN_ROOT=\cygwin
SET RUN=%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin\run -p /usr/bin

SET PATH=.;%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%

SET XAPPLRESDIR=
SET XCMSDB=
SET XKEYSYMDB=
SET XNLSPATH=

if not exist %CYGWIN_ROOT%\tmp\.X11-unix\X0 goto CLEANUP-FINISH
attrib -s %CYGWIN_ROOT%\tmp\.X11-unix\X0
del %CYGWIN_ROOT%\tmp\.X11-unix\X0

:CLEANUP-FINISH
if exist %CYGWIN_ROOT%\tmp\.X11-unix rmdir %CYGWIN_ROOT%\tmp\.X11-unix


if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto OS_NT

echo startxdmcp.bat - Starting on Windows 95/98/Me

goto STARTUP

:OS_NT

REM Windows NT/2000/XP
echo startxdmcp.bat - Starting on Windows NT/2000/XP

:STARTUP

%RUN% XWin -query tekknolagi.dyndns.org -clipboard -lesspointer -scrollbars -screen 0 1050x1655@2 -screen 1 1680x985@1
```

Comment: Maybe you can give some more details on how you do it in cygwin/X?

Comment: @tidbeck ok! updating the q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install an xserver on macos: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki

launch it in fullscreen.

Comment: installed; how do i launch fullscreen? and can I have the same effect?

Comment: okay i figured out fullscreen - how do i achieve this same effect?

Comment: which "effect"?

Comment: of the image i posted; a full x session

Comment: launch the apps you see in your screenshot on the mac. if you want to automate that: write a script (a so called 'session script').

Comment: that doesn't create the background and a whole separate window and everything

Comment: "the apps you see" also includes the tool which sets the background (xsetroot). with "the windowing" i assume you mean "the window management" .. and for that (which is also included in "the apps you see") launch twm.

Comment: why do you want to run a pseudo-xserver inside xquartz? and yes, if xnest is available in whatever form on macosx (think 'brew', think 'macports').. then you can start it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have privileges to install stuff on the linux (and OS X) machine you can install **NX Server/Player** from [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com). It will forward X sessions and only uses ssh for communication.

Comment: i have privileges, but is there another utility that does not require them?

Answer (score 0):

Recentish OS X systems come with an X server, but it's not installed by default. Install that, and it'll create X11.app. When you run that, you get a very different-looking terminal window. In there, do your ssh -X  and you'll have a local X server that will run applications from the server. Launch (for example) xEyes, and you'll see the app pop up on your Mac.

Regarding your batch script, that's a Windows script, and won't work on a Mac.

Comment: I realize it's a batch script, but that's how I recreate the image at the top. Is there a similar feature for Mac?

Comment: You can use shell scripts on a Mac instead. In fact, being as Mac OS X is UNIX, you'll probably be able to use scripts from the UNIX computer you're logging in to on the Mac.